# What is the number of free parameters for a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model

I am trying to use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to learn the structure of a DAG, G.

How is the number of free parameters of G calculated to compare the complexity of different graphical models?

Is it based on one of the following, or something else?

- Number of edges in the graph
- Maximum number of possible edges in the graph
- Maximum number of parents (children)

Comment: What do you mean by "number of free parameters of G"? Do you mean the number of parameters in the sampling distribution of the data for a particular G?

Comment: I feel obligated to tell you that learning the optimal structure of a Bayesian Network (which is a DAG) is in NP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) and hence not feasible. Does this question has any statistical background / aim or it is "just" a exercise in Combinatorics ?

Comment: @steffen: It is certainly feasible if the number of vertices p is relatively small (p<6 can be done by simple enumeration, and I think some of the more recent optimisation algorithms work for p<50). With a few restrictions on the type of graphs (say, limiting the number of parents of any vertex), you can easily step it up to even larger graphs.

Comment: @Simon With the introduction of restrictions, how can you be sure that the OPTIMAL structure will be found ? Nevertheless, I am interested in such optimisation algorithms ;) ... can you provide a link ?

Comment: @steffen: Well, it would be would be optimal from the class you consider. How do you know that any DAG is an appropriate model? (all models being wrong etc.) As far as algorithms go, the PC algorithm and its variants seems to be what all the cool kids are using these days.

Comment: @steffen: The question does have a statistical background and I am using a greedy optimization algorithm that starts with an empty graph and then adds/reverses/deletes edges according to the BIC.  I am also limiting the number of parents of vertices, as Simon mentioned.  The number of vertices I'm currently working with is relatively small (<20), but in the future I will extend it to > 200.

Comment: @Simon - Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I need the number of free parameters of G for inclusion in the BIC.  The number of nodes is fixed, but the number of edges can vary arbitrarily (with optional limits on the number of parents).  I could think of a few different reasonable ways to consider the number of free parameters (free parameters = # edges seems to be a weak criteria, free parameters = 1 parameter (for the number of edges) + # possible locations for these edges tends to work better), but do not know the mathematically correct model.

Comment: @hammer:I understand that, but you said you were fitting by maximum likelihood: what is your likelihood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your likelihood for the data $X$

1) Joint Gaussian

You can fit the model by sequentially fitting the conditional distribution of each node $v$ given its parents $\mathrm{pa}(v)$, in this case:

$X_v | X_{\mathrm{pa}(v)} \sim N\big(\mu_v + \beta_v^\top [X_{\mathrm{pa}(v)} - \mu_{\mathrm{pa}(v)}], \sigma_v^2 \big)$

Then for each node you need 1 parameter $\mu_v$ for the mean, 1 parameter $\sigma_v^2$ for the conditional variance and a vector $\beta_v$ of length $|\mathrm{pa}(v)|$.

So the total number of parameters needed for a graph $G=(V,E)$ is $2|V| + |E|$.

2) Discrete

Suppose the variable $X_v$ for each node $v$ is discrete with $n_v$ possible outcomes. Then for each possible outcome in the parent space, you require $n_v-1$ parameters. So for each node, you will need:

$(n_v-1) \prod_{u \in \mathrm{pa}(v)} n_u$

parameters. If each node has 2 possible outcomes, you will need:

$\sum_{v} 2^{|\mathrm{pa}(v)|}$

total parameters, unless you make some simplifying assumptions, such as proportional-odds (i.e. logistic regression).

Comment: In the discrete case, how do you treat the top node with no parents?

Comment: The product over the empty set is 1, so you would need n_v - 1 parameters (i.e. an n_v simplex)